# Crear nuevas tablas en SQLite

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite

Trabajo con **NodeJS**, hasta el momento, creaba nuevas filas cuando un usuario no era encontrado, y lo hacía de la siguiente manera:

```
const sqlite = require('sqlite');
sqlite.open('points.sqlite').then(() => {
  sqlite.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = ${user}`)
    .then(rows => {
      if (!rows) {
        sqlite.run('INSERT INTO users (ID) VALUES (?)', [`${user}`])
          .then(() => {
            sqlite.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = ${user}`)
              .then((row) => {
                if (!row) return;
                client.scores.set(row.ID, row);
              }).catch(console.log);
          });
      }
    }).catch(console.log);
});
```

Sin embargo, ahora quiero, con otra base de datos, llamado `lpoints.sqlite`, crear una tabla nueva con los siguientes campos:

```
CREATE TABLE `IDGUILD` (
    `IDUSER`    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    `SCORE` INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(`IDUSER`)
);
```

En la cual, `IDGUILD` sería la variable ID del guild (string de 18 caracteres).

¿Cómo puedo crear las tablas nuevas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solución, hacer `sqlite.run` en la cual se crea la tabla, con el nombre de la tabla y los campos. El formato para la creación de la tabla es: `sqlite.run(CREATE TABLE nombreTabla (var1 TYPE1, var2 TYPE2 ...))` [fuente](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) (en inglés).

```
const sqlite  = require('sqlite');
sqlite.open('lpoints.sqlite').then(() => {
  sqlite.run(`CREATE TABLE '${GUILDID}' (IDUSER TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, SCORE INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(IDUSER))`);
});
```

O en ES7 usando async/await:

```
new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
  try {
    const sqlite = require('sqlite');
    await sqlite.open('lpoints.sqlite')
    await sqlite.run(`CREATE TABLE '${GUILDID}' (IDUSER TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, SCORE INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(IDUSER))`);
    resolve();
  } catch(e) {
    reject(e);
  }
});
```